# Ingress doesn't redirect to my service after AppID on IKS

Tags: ibm-cloud, kubernetes-ingress, ibm-appid

I have an IKS cluster with AppID tied to it. I have a problem with redirecting an NodeJS app with the ingress. All other apps works with both AppID and ingress, but this one gives `500 Internal Server error` when redirecting back from AppID. The service works fine when used as a `NodePort` and accessed on the server address and that nodePort.

When describing the ingress I'm only getting successful results back

```
Events:
  Type    Reason   Age    From                                                             Message
  ----    ------   ----   ----                                                             -------
  Normal  Success  58m    public-cr9c603a564cff4a27adb020dd40ceb65e-alb1-59fb8fc894-s59nd  Successfully applied ingress resource.
```

My ingress looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      ingress.bluemix.net/appid-auth: bindSecret=binding-raven3-app-id namespace=default
        requestType=web serviceName=r3-ui
      ingress.bluemix.net/rewrite-path: serviceName=r3-ui rewrite=/;
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"ingress.bluemix.net/appid-auth":"bindSecret=binding-raven3-app-id namespace=default requestType=api serviceName=r3-ui [idToken=false]"},"name":"myingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"*host*","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"r3-ui","servicePort":3000},"path":"/"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["mydomain"],"secretName":"mytlssecret"}]}}
    creationTimestamp: "2019-06-20T10:31:57Z"
    generation: 21
    name: myingress
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "24140"
    selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/myingress
    uid: a15f74aa-9346-11e9-a9bf-f63d33811ba6
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: *host*
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: r3-ui
            servicePort: 3000
          path: /
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - *host*
      secretName: raven3
  status:
    loadBalancer:
      ingress:
      - ip: 169.51.71.141
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

and my service looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-06-20T09:25:30Z"
  labels:
    app: r3-ui
    chart: r3-ui-0.1.0
    heritage: Tiller
    release: r3-ui
  name: r3-ui
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "23940"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/r3-ui
  uid: 58ff6604-933d-11e9-a9bf-f63d33811ba6
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.21.180.240
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: r3-ui
    release: r3-ui
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
```

What's weird is that I'm getting different results on port 80 and on port 443. On port 80 I'm getting HTTP error 500 and on port 443 I'm getting `Invalid Host header`

Comment: Did you try this [tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/appid?topic=appid-kube-auth#kube-auth)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using https in order to access your application? For security reasons, App ID authentication only supports back ends with TLS/SSL enabled.

If you are using SSL and still having troubles, can you kindly share your Ingress and application logs so we can figure out what went wrong?

Thanks.